# Programming language for Sony Smart Watch

Tags: android, sony, sony-smartwatch

What Language can I use to create apps for the sony smart watch, I was looking at their [SDK](http://developer.sonymobile.com/tag/smartwatch/) but I couldn't find a language anywhere. Could it be C/C++ or Java?
If this type of question is not allowed on stackoverflow please tell me and I'll remove it

Comment: Just for guidance, you can look at: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic to know what you are and are not allowed to ask about. As far as this particular question, I don't know the answer, but best of luck :)

Comment: Thanks, so this isn't one of those questions that get locked and stuff and do -rep on me right? Wait, it isnt thanks again

Comment: I found the question to be a perfectly valid question, I am sure someone else is wondering the same thing. I simply provided the link to help you in the future ;)

Comment: Thank you, am tired of being on edge of getting banned from asking questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an add on to the Sony Add On, or so it appears. Anyway if you dig down in the documentation PDF, you will find:

> The APIs available in this version of the Sony Add-on SDK include the 
>   Camera Add-on API, the Smart Extension APIs, the Small Apps API, and
>   the IR remote API. To use this document to best effect, you should be
>   familiar with Java programming in an Android  environment.

So it's Java.

Comment: Thanks! I had been hoping it Java since I know nothing about C/C++

Comment: Right, as NickT posted it's Java, but more specifically it's basically a subset of the Android APIs so since you are an Android master you should be able to get it up and running in no time :).  Take a look at the SmartExtensions in the Sony Add-on SDK for more details.